# Wifi network switch in android

Tags: android

Currently i am working on the app of music player where dj is playing song and listener listen the music but it involve the network if the client and dj are on the same network then they  listen the perform there activity otherwise not so we have more then two wifi network the issue is this if the network 1 is closed mobile switch it network by default so my app is going to be crash i want to get the notification from the os if it changes it network from one hotspot to another any help we be appreciated  Thankx in advance

Answer (score 1):

I do it usually like this if I pull out a request:

```
private static final int NETWORK_TYPE_MOBILE = 0;
private static final int NETWORK_TYPE_WIFI = 1;
private static final int NETWORK_TYPE_ETHERNET = 9; //yep, cable

public static boolean checkForActiveNetworkOnDevice(Context applicationContext) {
    boolean deviceHasConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean deviceHasConnectedMobile = false;
    boolean deviceHasConnectedEthernet = false;

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] networkInfos = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfos != null) {
        for (NetworkInfo networkInfo : networkInfos) {
            if (NETWORK_TYPE_WIFI == networkInfo.getType()) {
                if (networkInfo.isConnected()) { deviceHasConnectedWifi = true;}
            }
            if (NETWORK_TYPE_MOBILE == networkInfo.getType()) {
                if (networkInfo.isConnected()) { deviceHasConnectedMobile = true;}
            }
            if (NETWORK_TYPE_ETHERNET == networkInfo.getType()) {
                if (networkInfo.isConnected()) { deviceHasConnectedEthernet = true; }
            }
        }
    }
    return deviceHasConnectedWifi || deviceHasConnectedMobile || deviceHasConnectedEthernet;
}

public static boolean checkForWifi(Context applicationContext) {
    boolean deviceHasConnectedWifi = false;

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] networkInfos = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfos != null) {
        for (NetworkInfo networkInfo : networkInfos) {
            if (NETWORK_TYPE_WIFI == networkInfo.getType()) {
                if (networkInfo.isConnected()) { deviceHasConnectedWifi = true;}
            }
        }
    }
    return deviceHasConnectedWifi;
}

public static boolean checkForEthernet(Context applicationContext) {
    boolean deviceHasConnectedEthernet = false;

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] networkInfos = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfos != null) {
        for (NetworkInfo networkInfo : networkInfos) {
            if (NETWORK_TYPE_ETHERNET == networkInfo.getType()) {
                if (networkInfo.isConnected()) { deviceHasConnectedEthernet = true;}
            }
        }
    }
    return deviceHasConnectedEthernet;
}
```

But If the device disconnects, you should get your MediaPlayer call your `OnErrorListener`. If that happens, you could check for connectivity again and if you got a network connection you could resume playback.

**Edit**
Oh it seems I misread your question, but I leave my answer, because you could check for a connection still.